# Receive encrypted string from server

Tags: windows, webserver, tcp

What is the easiest way (as easy as possible) to make a web server that will check a string received from client and respond with another string? How to do it from the very beginning to the very end? (I've never configured a server.)

I'm writing a Windows application and want it to work only for 30 days on a user's computer, and I don't think there's another safe option except online check (I use exe protector but trial expiration check is a weak spot because it's performed locally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it to be secure you will have to put some serious thought into the matter. My suggestion is nowhere near anything that is difficult to get around. You'll have to be the judge whether or not this is good enough to keep your user from using the application after the trial period has ended.

But you asked for as easy as possible, so:

Since you have never configured a server so you could get some low cost hosting.

Write a simple PHP service which takes a value you POST to it, performs whatever logic you need it to and then return a result to the client (i.e. your application).

You would place something along these lines in the PHP file (e.g. called validation.php):

```
function validateTrialPeriod( $fromClient )
{
    //logic for your validation
    //based on validation you return a result approving or blocking the client

    return $validationResult;
}

$receivedValue = $_POST['valueSentFromClient'];

$valueToSendToClient = validateTrialPeriod( $receivedValue);

echo $valueToSendToClient;
```

Of course the same thing can be achieved using .NET, Java, python etc., too, but depending on your budget you might have a harder time finding affordable hosting.

You will have to look into how you can communicate with web services in your application based on the technology you are using.